# How to offset footer ID to fixed position bottom

Tags: javascript

Currently this code applies an offset to the '#fixed' ID fixed element

I can't figure out how to apply the same effect in order to set the #footer ID to position fixed bottom

Since transform creates a new local coordinate system(W3C Spec), position: fixed is fixed to the origin of scrollbar content container, i.e. the left: 0, top: 0 point.

Therefore, you may need to register a scroll listener and apply offsets to the fixed element.

Can anyone offer any suggestions?

Code below:

```js
var fixedElem = document.getElementById('fixed');

var scrollbar = Scrollbar.init(
  document.getElementById('scroll'),
);

scrollbar.addListener(function(status) {
   var offset = status.offset;
  
  fixed.style.top = offset.y + 'px';
  fixed.style.left = offset.x + 'px';
});
```

```css
#scroll {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}

#fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: skyblue;
  text-align: center;
}

#footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: skyblue;
  text-align: center;
}

#fixed h1, #footer h1 {
  margin: 0;
}

#content {
  padding-top: 20px;
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/idiotWu/smooth-scrollbar/master/dist/smooth-scrollbar.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <main id="scroll">
    <header id="fixed">
      <h1>A fixed header</h1>
    </header>
    <article id="content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Distinctio amet, laudantium et ex, maiores labore minima quis incidunt quam magnam molestias, temporibus commodi! Laborum ipsam et aut quibusdam veniam animi.</p>
      <p>Illo, obcaecati modi laudantium, impedit ab dolorem optio sint fuga nisi, est earum, aliquam! Nam officia doloribus ad, facere architecto voluptatem labore, minima dicta dignissimos cumque ut assumenda, natus et!</p>
      <p>Odio velit vitae nisi consectetur molestiae repudiandae nemo quia qui in voluptatibus rerum iusto minus atque accusamus, autem, expedita incidunt magni voluptate itaque iure et cupiditate? Praesentium consectetur nesciunt at!</p>
      <p>Hic obcaecati laboriosam impedit doloribus numquam officia atque quia voluptatem deleniti sint ipsum debitis excepturi modi non tenetur corporis maxime magni aliquid, facere, saepe omnis, iusto architecto, aspernatur iste. Quae?</p>
      <p>Iste voluptatum rerum atque nesciunt sequi, dolore dicta error. Voluptas, quidem. Quasi aspernatur, culpa aliquid aperiam maxime sed voluptatum, saepe quis perferendis nulla sint possimus cumque, magnam voluptates hic accusantium?</p>
      <p>Ipsum, voluptates rerum repellendus illo fugiat, non aspernatur iure accusamus ullam recusandae quos? Veritatis accusantium, laudantium possimus rem, pariatur maxime itaque mollitia eos sapiente illum dolor adipisci ratione laborum iure.</p>
      <p>Laboriosam eius ipsum recusandae fuga aut nobis aperiam, veritatis ullam quod voluptatibus voluptatem voluptates labore quisquam ut tempora blanditiis cum, eaque illo nam sapiente autem debitis! Unde, quod necessitatibus cum?</p>
      <p>Sapiente iure distinctio vel qui enim, molestiae rerum fugit at non voluptate numquam doloremque a, obcaecati fugiat et debitis, magni alias eveniet cupiditate veritatis natus voluptates nostrum reprehenderit. Quidem, quam.</p>
      <p>Id fugiat at tenetur, architecto enim inventore accusamus asperiores quod! Dicta modi omnis sunt, laboriosam expedita et, ullam vel culpa odit consequuntur nobis provident id excepturi. Distinctio veniam, fuga temporibus?</p>
      <p>Voluptate soluta, sapiente quaerat, nulla iste similique adipisci natus amet. Deleniti perspiciatis, qui saepe, reprehenderit vero excepturi quo beatae at autem sed repellendus maxime repudiandae, tempore obcaecati similique! Distinctio, consequuntur!</p>
    </article>
     <footer id="footer">
       <h1>A fixed footer</h1>
     </footer>
     </main>
   
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: To pull out `<footer>` outside of the `<main>` or wrap `article` + `header` and apply "Scrollbar" function to that element?

Comment: I want #footer to behave the same as #fixed but have a fixed position of bottom: 0

Comment: Do you need this to work in IE?

Comment: Can we change the dom?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually `bottom: 0` is doing its job. It is anchored at the bottom of your scrolling article, but you want to anchored at the bottom of the main.

I wrap the `<main>` with another `<div>` and put `<header>` and `<footer>` there. This way you don't have to deal with scrolling y axis, no extra js calculation, no pixel-hardcoded css. The footer is in the right position out of the box. It basically create a window and see-through underlying `article`. Illustrated below.

[image]

```css
#scroll,
.main-wrap {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  position: relative;
}

#fixed,
#footer {
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
}

#fixed {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  background: skyblue;
  text-align: center;
}

#footer {
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  background: skyblue;
  text-align: center;
}

#fixed h1,
#footer h1 {
  margin: 0;
}

#content {
  padding-top: 20px;
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/idiotWu/smooth-scrollbar/master/dist/smooth-scrollbar.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="main-wrap">
    <header id="fixed">
      <h1>A fixed header</h1>
    </header>
    <footer id="footer">
      <h1>A fixed footer</h1>
    </footer>
    <main id="scroll">

      <article id="content">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Distinctio amet, laudantium et ex, maiores labore minima quis incidunt quam magnam molestias, temporibus commodi! Laborum ipsam et aut quibusdam veniam animi.</p>
        <p>Illo, obcaecati modi laudantium, impedit ab dolorem optio sint fuga nisi, est earum, aliquam! Nam officia doloribus ad, facere architecto voluptatem labore, minima dicta dignissimos cumque ut assumenda, natus et!</p>
        <p>Odio velit vitae nisi consectetur molestiae repudiandae nemo quia qui in voluptatibus rerum iusto minus atque accusamus, autem, expedita incidunt magni voluptate itaque iure et cupiditate? Praesentium consectetur nesciunt at!</p>
        <p>Hic obcaecati laboriosam impedit doloribus numquam officia atque quia voluptatem deleniti sint ipsum debitis excepturi modi non tenetur corporis maxime magni aliquid, facere, saepe omnis, iusto architecto, aspernatur iste. Quae?</p>
        <p>Iste voluptatum rerum atque nesciunt sequi, dolore dicta error. Voluptas, quidem. Quasi aspernatur, culpa aliquid aperiam maxime sed voluptatum, saepe quis perferendis nulla sint possimus cumque, magnam voluptates hic accusantium?</p>
        <p>Ipsum, voluptates rerum repellendus illo fugiat, non aspernatur iure accusamus ullam recusandae quos? Veritatis accusantium, laudantium possimus rem, pariatur maxime itaque mollitia eos sapiente illum dolor adipisci ratione laborum iure.</p>
        <p>Laboriosam eius ipsum recusandae fuga aut nobis aperiam, veritatis ullam quod voluptatibus voluptatem voluptates labore quisquam ut tempora blanditiis cum, eaque illo nam sapiente autem debitis! Unde, quod necessitatibus cum?</p>
        <p>Sapiente iure distinctio vel qui enim, molestiae rerum fugit at non voluptate numquam doloremque a, obcaecati fugiat et debitis, magni alias eveniet cupiditate veritatis natus voluptates nostrum reprehenderit. Quidem, quam.</p>
        <p>Id fugiat at tenetur, architecto enim inventore accusamus asperiores quod! Dicta modi omnis sunt, laboriosam expedita et, ullam vel culpa odit consequuntur nobis provident id excepturi. Distinctio veniam, fuga temporibus?</p>
        <p>Voluptate soluta, sapiente quaerat, nulla iste similique adipisci natus amet. Deleniti perspiciatis, qui saepe, reprehenderit vero excepturi quo beatae at autem sed repellendus maxime repudiandae, tempore obcaecati similique! Distinctio, consequuntur!</p>
      </article>

    </main>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for this! I am now attempting to implement this in my site but I am having an issue. My #scroll is 100% height so i set #footer top: 100%

The problem is that it now only appears on scroll - How can I make this appear on load? Otherwise it works perfectly

Comment: @glittergirl I updated my answer. It is more generic, see if that works for you.

Comment: Hey sorry I didn't explain well enough - I need the #footer to be inside the main because my footer is reasonably big and if hovered over footer you can't scroll the main

Comment: @glittergirl A big footer? I think you should put some effort to the UI design. Anyway, this is header and footer do not block the scrolling event.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need the site to work on IE, then you can use `[position][1]: sticky` to easily get the result you desire. Otherwise, stick to Mr. Brickowski's answer.

This doesn't have the issue where the footer will cover some of the content, though you will have to style the scrollbar yourself, unfortunately.

> Sticky positioning can be thought of as a hybrid of relative and fixed
>   positioning. A stickily positioned element is treated as relatively
>   positioned until it crosses a specified threshold, at which point it
>   is treated as fixed until it reaches the boundary of its parent.

CSS settings of note: you need to set #scroll to have an overflow, and #fixed and #footer to `position: sticky`, and that takes care of it. Sticky will be sticky to the closest ancestor with a "scrolling mechanism". There is no JavaScript required for using this.

```
#scroll {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

#fixed {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background: skyblue;
  text-align: center;
}

#footer {
  position: sticky;
  bottom: 0;
  background: skyblue;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```css
#scroll {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

#fixed {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background: skyblue;
  text-align: center;
}

#footer {
  position: sticky;
  bottom: 0;
  background: skyblue;
  text-align: center;
}

#fixed h1,
#footer h1 {
  margin: 0;
}

#content {
  padding-top: 20px;
  background: orange;
}

#content>:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}


/* From css-tricks https://css-tricks.com/the-current-state-of-styling-scrollbars/
*/

html {
  --scrollbarBG: #CFD8DC;
  --thumbBG: #90A4AE;
}

#scroll::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 11px;
}

#scroll {
  scrollbar-width: thin;
  scrollbar-color: var(--thumbBG) var(--scrollbarBG);
}

#scroll::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: var(--scrollbarBG);
}

#scroll::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: var(--thumbBG);
  border-radius: 6px;
  border: 3px solid var(--scrollbarBG);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <main id="scroll">
    <header id="fixed">
      <h1>A fixed header</h1>
    </header>
    <article id="content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Distinctio amet, laudantium et ex, maiores labore minima quis incidunt quam magnam molestias, temporibus commodi! Laborum ipsam et aut quibusdam veniam animi.</p>
      <p>Illo, obcaecati modi laudantium, impedit ab dolorem optio sint fuga nisi, est earum, aliquam! Nam officia doloribus ad, facere architecto voluptatem labore, minima dicta dignissimos cumque ut assumenda, natus et!</p>
      <p>Odio velit vitae nisi consectetur molestiae repudiandae nemo quia qui in voluptatibus rerum iusto minus atque accusamus, autem, expedita incidunt magni voluptate itaque iure et cupiditate? Praesentium consectetur nesciunt at!</p>
      <p>Hic obcaecati laboriosam impedit doloribus numquam officia atque quia voluptatem deleniti sint ipsum debitis excepturi modi non tenetur corporis maxime magni aliquid, facere, saepe omnis, iusto architecto, aspernatur iste. Quae?</p>
      <p>Iste voluptatum rerum atque nesciunt sequi, dolore dicta error. Voluptas, quidem. Quasi aspernatur, culpa aliquid aperiam maxime sed voluptatum, saepe quis perferendis nulla sint possimus cumque, magnam voluptates hic accusantium?</p>
      <p>Ipsum, voluptates rerum repellendus illo fugiat, non aspernatur iure accusamus ullam recusandae quos? Veritatis accusantium, laudantium possimus rem, pariatur maxime itaque mollitia eos sapiente illum dolor adipisci ratione laborum iure.</p>
      <p>Laboriosam eius ipsum recusandae fuga aut nobis aperiam, veritatis ullam quod voluptatibus voluptatem voluptates labore quisquam ut tempora blanditiis cum, eaque illo nam sapiente autem debitis! Unde, quod necessitatibus cum?</p>
      <p>Sapiente iure distinctio vel qui enim, molestiae rerum fugit at non voluptate numquam doloremque a, obcaecati fugiat et debitis, magni alias eveniet cupiditate veritatis natus voluptates nostrum reprehenderit. Quidem, quam.</p>
      <p>Id fugiat at tenetur, architecto enim inventore accusamus asperiores quod! Dicta modi omnis sunt, laboriosam expedita et, ullam vel culpa odit consequuntur nobis provident id excepturi. Distinctio veniam, fuga temporibus?</p>
      <p>Voluptate soluta, sapiente quaerat, nulla iste similique adipisci natus amet. Deleniti perspiciatis, qui saepe, reprehenderit vero excepturi quo beatae at autem sed repellendus maxime repudiandae, tempore obcaecati similique! Distinctio, consequuntur!</p>
    </article>
    <footer id="footer">
      <h1>A fixed footer</h1>
    </footer>
  </main>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your reply! The problem is that the smooth scrollbar plugin is no longer working with this solution

Comment: @glittergirl, I've added some scrollbar stylings based on https://css-tricks.com/the-current-state-of-styling-scrollbars/, It should be pretty close to being the same cross browser without the need for a JS library. Just thought you might be interested in a more pure CSS approach to some of these older problems :)